# Android hide childView in BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using BaseExpandableListAdapter in my app to show a list of company names. when you click on the company name a second list of company branches should show.

The data structure behind the list is an String array[companies][branches].

due to the choice of array, i have to instantiate it before using it. There will never be more than 10 branches per company so i declare it as arr[companyListLength][10];

The problem is that when a company has less than 10 branches, there are empty rows in the child list.

I've tried setting convertView to null if the data in the row is null.

I've also tried setting convertView.setVisibility(View.Gone)

but neither work.

How can i hide rows in the child list if there is no data?

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

      private Context myContext;
      public ExpAdapter(Context context) {
       myContext = context;
      }
      @Override
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
       }

       TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
       tvPlayerName.setText(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);

       if(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition] == null){

           Log.e(TAG, "child null");
       }else{
         Log.e(TAG, "child not null");
       }

       return convertView;
      }

      @Override
      public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       return arrChildelements[groupPosition].length;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      public int getGroupCount() {
       return arrGroupelements.length;
      }

      @Override
      public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
       }

       TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
       tvGroupName.setText(arrGroupelements[groupPosition]);

       return convertView;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean hasStableIds() {
       return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return true;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) return the count of non-null children, something like:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrChildelements[groupPosition].length; i++)
    count += arrChildelements[groupPosition][i] != null ? 1 : 0;
  return count;
}
```